# Android TextView in RecyclerView.Adapter setMaskFilter copied on other TextView

Tags: android

I have three TextView in RecyclerView.Adapter view;

Some TextView must be blur

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    Item item = itemsList.get(i);

    tv1.setText("00");
    tv2.setText("Text View 1");
    tv3.setText("Text View 2");
    if (item.needBlur) {
        tv1.setText("99");
        tv2.setText("BLUR  Text View 1");
        tv3.setText("BLUR  Text View 2");

        DoTextViewBlur(tv1);
        DoTextViewBlur(tv2);
        DoTextViewBlur(tv3);
    }
}

private void DoTextViewBlur(TextView tv) {
    float radius = tv.getTextSize() / 3;
    BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.OUTER);
    tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    tv.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
}
```

But in result blur on the correct TextView and some other

[image]

Why blur "copied" to other TextView?

Comment: When do you change the value of `needBlur`? Care that in a recyclerview the views will be recycled. So if you have a view in which you set the blur filter the next view will have the same blur filter when it's getting recycled. You never remove the blur filter...

Comment: @beeb I was edit code. needBlur is get correct (you can see text on screenshot)

Comment: Can you try to use `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` for layer type?

Comment: @beeb I use "android:hardwareAccelerated="true". If use "LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE" not show texts

Comment: But as you can see here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html it is not supported...

Comment: @beeb I`m sorry, don`t understand how create blur. after tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);         tv.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter); - not draw any text

Comment: Well you have also have to set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` on your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`